# start with a random function and then alternate (Python)

Tags: python

I created a set of functions to find the probability that Luke, a sleepwalker, would escape from his room, represented by 9 boxes. Luke starts in the center of the 3x3 square, (0,0) and can move right/left or up/down (he must alternate between right/left and up/down with every step, eg cannot go right left or right right). Luke escapes by walking out of the doors on either side of him (2,0) or (-2,0)

I have the basic game written out, but I'm tying my head into knots on how to get Luke to start in a random direction. As code shows below i have him going right/left first. I'd like it to have an equal chance going either direction for Luke's first step, and then alternating directions. Any idea how to do this?

```
import random

def checkXState(x):
    right=x+1;
    left=x-1;
    xc = random.choice([right,left])
    return xc

def checkYState(y): 
    up=y+1;
    down=y-1;
    yc = random.choice([up,down]);
    return yc


def theRule(x,y):
    #the Rule determines whether Luke is awake or not, and is applied to each step
    if (x==2 and y == 0) or (x==-2 and y==0):
        return 'Luke has ESCAPED';
    elif (x==2 or x==-2 or y==2 or y==-2):
        return 'Luke is AWAKE';

def theGame():
        x=0;
        y=0;
        while True: 
                x = checkXState(x); #Luke goes right or left, new x coord stored in x
                print(x,y);
                a = theRule(x,y);
                if a==('Luke is AWAKE' or 'Luke has ESCAPED'):
                        print(a)
                        break;
                y = checkYState(y);
                print(x,y);
                b = theRule(x,y);
                if b==('Luke is AWAKE' or 'Luke has ESCAPED'):
                        print(b)
                        break;
```

Comment: I may not have fully understood the problem. What happens if Luke is at y=1 and x=2 and wants to go right?

Comment: if y=1 and x=2 luke hits a wall and wakes up. The function ends there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
directions = ["up", "down", "left", "right"]

start_dir = random.choice(directions)

if start_dir == "left" or start_dir == "right":
    checkXstate(x)
else:
    checkYstate(y)
```

Comment: i see how this chooses random direction for the first step, but how do you alternate directions after this? Maybe a while loop inside each of the conditioned statements would work

Comment: Put the start_dir and if parts inside your while loop.

Comment: If you used this, please mark the answer as correct!

Comment: I ended up putting the while loop inside the conditions instead, and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. If it's enough for you to get a pseudo-equally-distributed decision on where to go first, you could just use `random` as well for your first-step decision. (This is what you seem to be doing right now. *EDIT: Actually you're not exactly doing that already but marienbad's answer solves this problem which also might have been your intented question which I didn't understand first. I hope this will still be a bit useful.*)
2. If you want to correctly calculate the probabilities that he's escaping from his room, the random direction changes after the first step are not the right way to do this (because obviously it's just random and it could in an extremely rare case also lead to Luke never escaping the room). The actual solution would e.g. be something like simulating all possibilities and then getting the proportion `#escaping / #all`. (You could do this with [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) - as an example.)
3. If you really just care about the first step being "equally distributed" then you could do the same thing like described in 2. - but only with the first step. That means simulating the whole thing 4 times with the 4 possible first steps and then adding all resulting probabilities together and dividing them by 4. However, due to the fact that at the moment you're not really printing any probabilities, I'm not a 100% sure if that is what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

Why not a simple if statement and use srand to get a random number, and then just use an if case to see which it is equal to.

Be aware this is pseudo random but given that it's a game it doesn't really pose any security issues.

```
int start_choice = srand(2) + 1;

if(start_choice == 1) {x = checkXState(x); }
if else (start_choice == 2) { y = checkYState(y); }
else() {}
```